# events page of Event Calendar not redirecting for logged out users

Tags: the-events-calendar, plugin-events-calendar

I’m using Suremembers plugin to restrict my site excluding some of its pages for logged out users and for some reason, it doesn’t seem to be working only in the events page. I also tried adding a custom code to redirect but also didn’t work. I believe it's an Event Calendar plugin issue maybe because of its template but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
function redirect_events_page_for_logged_out_users() {
// Check if the user is logged in
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_post_type_archive( 'tribe_events' ) ) {
    // Redirect to a specific page URL for logged-out users
    wp_redirect( home_url( '/login/' ) ); // Replace '/login/' with the URL you want to redirect to
    exit;
}
}
 add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_events_page_for_logged_out_users' );
```

Other pages works except for the /events page and I get a white screen of death.

Comment: If you've narrowed it down to an issue with The Events Calendar, you'll need to check with their support team. (If you haven't, I'd recommend you try [doing some debugging](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) to see if you can ascertain the exact cause of the problem.) Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.